# Removing Background Blur Or Black Theme In Alert Dialog Box

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-api-3, android-alertdialog

this is my code ,is not working correctly.....

getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
direction_Alert_Box.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
direction_Alert_Box.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```